# from ncclient import manager ; unable to call close_session()

Tags: python, netconf

I am trying to execute following code but I am getting these errors for "close_session()" function. how to fix it? I am new to python.

I am learning netconf and trying to configure router using python netconf. I have imported library and it seems I have done everything correctly.

```
from ncclient import manager
from pprint import pprint
import xmltodict
import xml.dom.minidom
from router_info import router



print(router["host"])
print(router["port"])
print(router["username"])
print(router["password"])


netconf_filter = open("/Users/ljames/netconf/netconf-filter.xsd").read()

with manager.connect(host=router["host"], port=router["port"], username=router["username"], password=router["password"], hostkey_verify=False) as m:
   
      interface_netconf = m.get(netconf_filter)
     #   xmlDom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(str(interface_netconf))
     #   print(xmlDom.toprettyxml(indent=''))
     #   print('*' * 25 + 'Break' + '*' * 25)

interface_python = xmltodict.parse(interface_netconf.xml)["rpc-reply"]["data"]
# pprint(interface_python)
name = interface_python['interfaces']['interface']['name']['#text']
print(name)

config = interface_python["interfaces"]["interface"]
op_state = interface_python["interfaces-state"]["interface"]

print("Start")
print(f"Name: {config['name']['#text']}")
print(f"Description: {config['description']}")
print(f"packets In {op_state['statistics']['in-unicast-pkts']}")
m.close_session()
```

Following is the error msg:

```
mac@user % /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/ljames/netconf/netconf-5.py
ios-xe-mgmt-latest.cisco.com
10000
developer
C1sco12345
GigabitEthernet2
Start
Name: GigabitEthernet2
Description: YJ-interface
packets In 146
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ljames/netconf/netconf-5.py", line 36, in <module>
    m.close_session() 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ncclient/manager.py", line 231, in execute
    return cls(self._session,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ncclient/operations/session.py", line 28, in request
    return self._request(new_ele("close-session"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ncclient/operations/rpc.py", line 327, in _request
    self._session.send(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ncclient/transport/session.py", line 167, in send
    raise TransportError('Not connected to NETCONF server')
ncclient.transport.errors.TransportError: Not connected to NETCONF server
```

Comment: FYI, your password is in the post

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and this is my conclusion:

The issue could be that you use `m.close_session()` outside of `with` block. In fact, you should not use `close_session` at all within `with` block, since cleanup is performed automatically. Just debug line by line and see that when you exit `with` block, `m.connected` is set to false.

Answer (score -1):

check your host and password for ncclient manager

Comment: Please elaborate.